# Compact subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Consider the set $$A=\{(x.y) \in \Bbb{R}^2: x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}=1\} \subset \Bbb{R}^2$$

How to prove $A$ is compact with respect to the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}^2$ ?

My try:

It is enough to check $A$ is closed and bounded.

Since $A$ is a inverse image of $\{1\}$ under the continuous map $(x,y) \mapsto x^\frac{2}{3}+y^\frac{2}{3}$, it is closed.

It is bounded, since $\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{y^2}=1$ implies $\vert x \vert \leq 1$ and $\vert y \vert \leq 1$.

My Questions are:

1) Is my approach correct?  If not, what is the mistake in my answer and how to prove further ?

2) How to draw this graph (generally this type of graphs)  in a plane ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $(-\pi)^{2/3}$?

Comment: Sir....,generally $x^\frac{a}{b}$ = b th root of ($x^ a$), so can i write $(- \pi)^\frac{2}{3}$= cube root of $(- \pi)^2$?

Comment: @LearningMathematics It's generally a problem trying to define fractional exponents of negative numbers. It's a bit difficult to spot the problem with $\frac23$ (and maybe what you wrote is indeed what was intended from the author of your problem), but think about $(-\pi)^{1/3}$. Now, $\frac13$ and $\frac26$ are really just two different ways of writing the same number, so whichever value you think $(-\pi)^{1/3}$ is, then $(-\pi)^{2/6}$ ought to be the same. What value is that?

Comment: As long as we work over the reals, both $t\mapsto t^{1/3}$ and $t\mapsto t^2$ are well-defined (as real maps). We only have to check that their compositions commute, i.e., $(t^2)^{1/3}=(t^{1/3})^2$, but that it's an easy exercise, which follows from the usual properties of integer powers and that $t\mapsto t^{1/3}$ is the inverse of the bijective map $t\mapsto t^3$. I didn't see anywhere that the OP was referring to complex valued maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. I'd describe the intended set as
$$A:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\bigm||x|^{2/3}+|y|^{2/3}=1\bigr\}\ .$$
Note that the set $A$ is symmetric with respect to both axes. For a plot of the part in the first quadrant you can plot the function
$$y=f(x):=\sqrt{(1-x^{2/3})^3}\qquad(0\leq x\leq 1)\ ,$$
or you can use the parametric representation
$$t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr):=\bigl(\cos^3 t,\sin^3 t\bigr)\qquad\left(0\leq t\leq{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$

Comment: ok sir...I agree with your answer. Can you give any idea to plot this figure?